# Access uniquely-identifying information about Android App programmatically?

Tags: android, google-play

When you upload your .apk to Google Play you are issued with a Base64-encoded RSA public key as your License key. How does one access this same key programmatically in their Android app code?

Secondly, does this key remain constant, or does it change every time you upload an update for a given app (generated presumably from the .apk binary)?

If so, is there any other uniquely-identifying information you can get programmatically from an app that will remain constant regardless of updates. Something that identifies a particular app definitively?

Trivial example, if a library is proprietary but you want to configure it to only work with a pre-determined set of Android apps. You could do this by verifying against some programmatically accessible unique information about the app in which it is being used at runtime.

Many thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are confusing the keys used for license verification and in-app billing with those you use to sign your apps. You can get the signing key [with this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/Signature.html). The license key is not used by most apps, and if you need it, you have to embed it in the app. Generally, an app is uniquely identified by the package name and signing certificate (or its hash value).

Comment: Thanks for clearing up my confusion. So I could in theory verify an app's identity using the signing certificate and package name.. could this be subject to change with updates, or is it constant? Could you please provide me with a code example to cement my understanding? Thanks again for your response

Comment: The Play Store enforces the same certificate for the package, so it doesn't change. If you get the app from somewhere else, it might have been repackaged and signed with a different key. Not clear exactly what you want to do, so hard to produce a sample. You can get the package with (surprise!) `getPackage()`, `PackageManger` has  some helpful methods as well.

Comment: The fact that the app can be repackaged is not a concern. Based on what you've said would something like this reliably work to get unique information about the app (assuming SomeContextHandle is some handle to Context): SomeContextHandle.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(SomeContextHandle.getPackageName(),PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES).signatures? OR getPackage().getHashCode()?? Sorry for being uneducated in this regard!

Comment: How does one get the 'certificate for the package'?

Comment: Looks OK. The so called 'signature' is actually the encoded certificate. There is usually only one, so `signatures[0]` should get it.